# Accessibility and SVG Text

Tags: svg, accessibility

We are receiving accessibility validation errors from worldspace / fireeyes for color contrast on some of our text that is over a semi transparent background or over a gradient background.

In interest of keeping our web design intact, a solution seems to be to use SVG text in these cases. W3C seems to be good with it, and it passes on FireEyes.

However, I don't know if I'm cheating or not. Graphically it would still look the same on the page, including contrast.

- Does color contrast not matter as much with SVG's? Is it ok to be
  below the 4.5:1 contrast ration on SVG text?
- Are accessibility tools somehow able to deal with SVG's more easily
  than typical text?
- Are there other concerns unique to SVG text that may arise if we
  switch?

We are not worried about having to deal with older browsers so early IE is not an issue.

Comment: I suspect it is the later. But I am not certain and have't tested it. I will. I agree with what you're saying, but in my limited research I was getting the impression that things like using high contrast screens were made easier with SVG and therefor (I inferred) wouldn't require as strict of a ratio.

Comment: I just tested black SVG text on a black SVG polygon and it didn't raise an error so it doesn't check.

Comment: @unobf [gradient example](https://jsfiddle.net/831er1a9/)

Comment: [semi-transparent background example](https://jsfiddle.net/mertens3d/n52es554/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are cheating. But if you think that it's because FireEyes (or another tool) can't handle the exact background of your text perfectly (because of transparency, or gradient background), it may not be necessary.

Switching to SVG will still imply that you have enough contrast, and it's not because some tool will tell you that your site is OK, that it will be accessible.

You are not doing accessibility to satisfy a tool, but to serve people.

Comment: if you modified this to read "it may not be necessary", it would be more accurate. Just because there is a gradient/image background does not mean that FireEyes gets the calculation wrong. It does get it right often enough for us to heave decided to leave the calculation in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am in charge of the FireEyes product at Deque Systems. FireEyes does handle background gradients and background images (although there can be false positives when complex images with many different colors are behind text).

FireEyes does not handle SVG text. But SVG text is not well supported by assistive technologies. So you can assume that SVG text is, by definition, not accessible.

The SVG image background is not supported by FireEyes. Could you create jsfiddles of your examples and maybe we can update the product to support these cases better.

Comment: I will add some contrast, "many different colors behind text" is just the definition of a gradient image. You can't assume that by testing some pixels in the image, you will get a 100% correct answer. Note that the text color can use gradient definition too. With all my respect, you should have said that FireEyes is one of the rare tools which tries to check for the background image, but this can give false positives or false negatives. Would modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Adam - you are correct, but WCAG 2 itself does not specify what to do in instances like this. Admittedly, a human will probably be better at picking a representative pixel than an algorithm but that does not mean that the algorithm does not get it right sometimes.

Comment: Totally agree with you. Tools have to implement this function, as a false alarm is better than no alarm at all.

Comment: @unobf - I've added examples to the comments below my original question. Thanks